# update the choice list of django model using django Admin panel

Tags: django, django-models

my model is currently as follows :

```
class Food(model.Model):
    CUISINE_CHOICES = (
        ('1', 'Chinese'),
        ('2', 'French'),
        ('3', 'Italian'),
        ('4', 'Indian'),
        ('5', 'Japanese'),
        ('6', 'Moroccan'),
        ('7', 'Spanish'),
        ('8', 'Thai'),
    )
    Cuisine = models.CharField(max_length = 20,choices = CUISINE_CHOICES,default = '1')
    Dish = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
```

Is there a way by which I can update the `CUISINE_CHOICES` list in future from the admin panel.
Say I need to add Arabian as the 9th cuisine. I know that manually updating the cuisine_choices list will resolve it, I want to know if i can do the same from Admin Panel. If yes, How ?

I've searched for similar questions/ solutions but could not find one that matches my requirement.

TIA.

Comment: If `CUISINE_CHOICES` changes at run time, why don't you use [`models.Foreignkey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) instead of using hard-coded choices?

Comment: I actually have a profile model where in I plan to have a favourite dish field and to handle that I had created a new model. But your suggestion makes sense, I will create a Cuisine model, use that as foreignkey in food model and finally use that as foreign key in profile model's faviourite dish field. 

Thank you for the quick inputs.